# template typename instantiation error

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename List>
class list_base {
    typedef typename List::node node;

};


template <typename T, typename Allocator = allocator<T>>
class list: private list_base<list<T, Allocator>> {
    typedef Allocator allocator_type;

    class node {

    };
};
```

When I instantiate `list<int> x` it gives me an error:

```
../src/Console.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class list_base<list<int> >’:
../src/Console.cpp:27:7:   required from ‘class list<int>’
../src/Console.cpp:36:12:   required from here
../src/Console.cpp:21:30: error: no type named ‘node’ in ‘class list<int>’
```

Type node clearly is defined. What happens here ?

Answer (score 2):

Question:

> Type node clearly is defined. What happens here ?

`list` is not completely defined when the base class is instantiated.